# Expressions should not be too complex for conditional operators

Tags: java, android, sonarqube

I am using Sonar and its giving me the suggestion `"Expressions should not be too complex"`

How can I make a better representation of below code?

Code

```
   if (eDelivery != null && Boolean.parseBoolean(eDelivery.getReceiveConfirmationElectronically()) &&
                            !Boolean.parseBoolean(eDelivery.getInvalidEmailAddress()) && !Boolean.parseBoolean(eDelivery.getEmailUndeliverable()) &&
                            eDelivery.getUserEmailAddress() != null && !eDelivery.getUserEmailAddress().isEmpty()) {
                        // Implementation code
    }
```

Comment: try reading this https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1067?layout=false and break your condition into small functions

Comment: Alternatively, just leave it as it is. I don't find it difficult to read.

Comment: The sonar error explanation is the number of conditions. It even gives you examples of refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These conditions all relate to the `eDelivery` object, so deal with this there.

First, there's the question of why you're doing all these `parseBoolean` calls for properties that look like they should be boolean to start with. But okay, let's assume that you can't change that. Fine, so add 2ndary methods:

```
public class EDelivery {

  public boolean isReceiveConfirmationElectronically() {
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(getReceiveConfirmationElectronically())
  }

  // &etc...
```

Already that cleans it up considerably:

```
if (eDelivery != null && eDelivery.isReceiveConfirmationElectronically() &&
                        !eDelivery.isInvalidEmailAddress() && !eDelivery.isEmailUndeliverable() &&
                        eDelivery.getUserEmailAddress() != null && !eDelivery.getUserEmailAddress().isEmpty()) {
                    // Implementation code
```

But that doesn't address the *number* of conditions. So now:

```
  // in EDelivery class
  public boolean isEmailGood() {
    return !isInvalidEmailAddress() && !isEmailUndeliverable() &&
                        getUserEmailAddress() != null && !getUserEmailAddress().isEmpty())
  }
```

So now we're at:

```
if (eDelivery != null && eDelivery.isReceiveConfirmationElectronically() &&
                        eDelivery.isEmailGood()) {
                    // Implementation code
```

At this point you've met the requirement, but if you wanted to take it a little further:

```
  // in EDelivery class
  public boolean canSendElectronicConfirmation(){
    return isEmailGood() && isReceiveConfirmationElectronically();
  }
```

Which reduces your original `if` statement to

```
if (eDelivery != null && eDelivery.canSendElectronicConfirmation()) {
                    // Implementation code
```

Comment: Also, `getUserEmailAddress() != null && !getUserEmailAddress().isEmpty()` can be shortened in a number of situation (CommonsLang, Guava, Android, Google Base, ...)

Comment: Is there a way we can configure SonarQube to ignore Equals and Hashcode methods when checking this rule? Or should we manually mark these as ignore, or false positives? Those methods are generally automatically generated and an even simple domain object with just 5 or 6 fields will easily have an equals method with more than the minimum number of conditions. Thoughts?

Comment: @KevinM are you sure you're talking about the same rule? I don't remember seeing an auto-generated Equals method that tests every field in one long condition.

Comment: If you have 6 class level variables for a pojo for example and then use your IDE to generate an equals method using all fields, that will result in at least 6 conditionals

Comment: I probably should try to simplify the logic of what it means to be equal. But in some cases like when using a persistence framework, you don't always have an identifier yet, until you save the object. So you really have to have an equals method that compares all fields, not just the id

Comment: But what if EDelivery is an ORM model class and you are trying to do op's action in some repository? You usually don't want to add any logic to models. Isn't there any other way to split it?